# How to host token gated content on Wix website

Tags: tokens, nft

I'm creating an NFT website and using Wix as the development platform. I have implemented minting possibilities using ThirdWeb.
Now I want to implement token-gated content that allows people to connect their wallet to the site and access unique content if they have the right NFT.
If any of you have experience with this or have done this before, it would be nice to have tips on how to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: You can check out the Token Gated Website example repo here!
https://portal.thirdweb.com/templates/token-gated-membership

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it would go something like this:

1. User [signs message](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html) to log on, which confirms that it's them
2. Backend of your website verifies the signature
3. If the signature is valid and the wallet holds the right NFT, serve the user a webpage with exclusive content

This is similar to how websites like [Opensea](https://opensea.io/) let you "log on"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the API endpoint from 3mint.io

```
curl -X POST https://api.3mint.io/api/v1/tokenGate   
   -H "Content-Type: application/json"
   -H "X-API-KEY: [YOUR_API_KEY]"
   -d '{"walletAddress": "[WALLET_OF_USER]",
       "requirements": [
           {
               "contractAddress": "[PROJECT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS]",
               "chain": "ethereum",
               "network": "mainnet",
               "contractType": "ercnft",
               "minBalance": 1,
               "minTime": "0.6.0.0.0"
           }
         ] 
       }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve the same for one of my Wix website and I could get it working to some extent. I created Web3.js code snippet for token gating and added in on my Wix site using injected Javascript.

```
balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(contract_address);
```

It was good enough for my needs.

You can also use opensea.io APIs instead of Web3.js to fetch NFTs balance.

```
https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?owner={wallet-address}
```

There was also a [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oXd5MfKkbg) I found and these guys were claiming that they provide a solution without injected JavaScript. Not sure how they have done it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using thirdweb I am assuming you know how to get the wallet address.

You can use 3rd party web3 APIs services like Moralis to get the NFTs owned by a wallet on a specific smart contract.
Here is a sample example code to achieve this.

```js
if (!Moralis.Core.isStarted) {
    await Moralis.start({ apiKey: "Moralis_API_KEY" });
  }

  const nftList = await Moralis.EvmApi.nft.getWalletNFTs({
    chain: "0x1", //chain Id
    address: "0x..", // User Wallet Address
    tokenAddresses: ["0x..."], // NFT contract on which you want to verify ownership 
  });

  if(nftList.raw.result?.length){
    // Show NFT gated content
  }
  else{
    // Hide NFT gated content
  }
```

This code checks the NFTs of a wallet address on a `chain` and NFT contract address added in `tokenAddresses` array. When you get a response from this code check the owned NFTs from the result array in response object and then show/hide the NFT-gated content based on it.

This is as far the simple and best solution for setting up token-gated content on any website.

I hope this helps.